# Nginx brew service showed as started but isn't working

Tags: nginx, homebrew

I'm having some problems running Nginx, I installed it but when I run:

```
brew services list
```

This is what I got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZZeA.png)

If I run:

```
sudo brew services restart nginx
```

This is what I got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TSzi.png)

I already tried to uninstall and reinstall Nginx but when I visit http://localhost:8080 it never show the Welcome to Nginx page.

I'm using macOS Mojave

Thoughts?

Thanks you.

Comment: `telnet localhost 8080`? Is nginx listening on port `8080` at all? `netstat -an | grep 8080`

Answer (score 0):

Nginx by default do not listen on port 8080 it will be port 80. You can check that by `http://localhost:80` or `http://localhost`

Methods to debug that you should consider

- You can check if Nginx is running and the port it is listening to with `netstat -vanp` or `netstat -tlnp` with `sudo`.
- Check Nginx error and access logs at `/var/log/nginx/` if there are any errors.
- Check your Nginx configuration at `/etc/nginx/` and check for the `listen` directive for the port number it might be listening to. By default the file might be `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and the line will be `listen 80 default_server;`

You should check the documentaion for more details: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found why Nginx wasn't working and it was because I modified the `nginx.conf` adding these two lines:

```
passenger_rooto/usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /Users/Daniel/.rbenv/shims/passenger;
```

That caused Nginx will not work properly.